# Checking for validation using a switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to set up conditional rendering using in the backend for allowing a user to update their profile. My first thought was to use a switch statement since it is a case by case on what they want to update (username, location, etc.), however I cannot get the validation to work case-by-case. Is there a more efficient way of doing this without using ReactJS? Below is the code and error log. I have removed the "break" clause in order for the switch to keep going in checking for an actual value. I have also tried ".trim().length" as part of the validation but the validation error i posted keeps popping as well.

profile.js

```
router.post("/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log("UPDATING ROUTE HIT \n");

  try {
    console.log("MADE IT INSIDE THE TRY ROUTE \n");
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      User.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (foundUser) {
          console.log("FOUND USER \n");
          const newUpdate = {
            username: req.body.username,
            company: req.body.company,
            location: req.body.location,
            position: req.body.position,
          };
          switch (true) {
            // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            case newUpdate.username !== "" && newUpdate.username !== User.find({ username: { $ne: null } }):
              foundUser.username = newUpdate["username"];
            case newUpdate.company !== "" && newUpdate.company.length >= 3:
              foundUser.company = newUpdate["company"];
            case newUpdate.location !== "" && newUpdate.location.length >= 3:
              foundUser.location = newUpdate["location"];
            case newUpdate.position !== "" && newUpdate.position.length >= 3:
              foundUser.position = newUpdate["position"];
              break;
            default:
              console.log("FAILED TO ENTER ANYTHING" + err + "\n");
              break;
          }
          foundUser.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("THERE WAS AN ERROR: " + err + "\n");
            } else {
              console.log("SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED POSITION");
            }
          });
          res.redirect("/profile");
        } else {
          console.log("FOUND THE ANSWER" + err + "\n");
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("THERE WAS AN ERROR(caught): " + error + "\n");
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use if statements instead of the switch?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wanted a way to continue the full function if only one or more trigger true, without putting in multiple if/elseif clauses. Does continue or pass work in Javascript  to continue to the next statement?

Comment: If you want to exit the function if something is false, return early?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I dont want to exit the function if its false. I have four inputs that will allow people to change their name, location, company and position. Lets say, they only want to change their name and location. Those two will return true, but the rest return false. So I took out the break/return so that the switch will keep going checking for "True" validity at each case until the last condition and then break out of the switch. If the case does not pass then only the ones that pass will execute and it will save at the end. My issue is input tags not returning null inputs but " "

Comment: I guess what I could do is just four if statements you said earlier and then just save at the end, rather than use a loop. That seems more efficient now that I think about it. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Need more information to help you out. Are you able to share the repo link and the request for which you are getting this error?

Comment: @dina I figured out my issue. I am uploading below, but I since the switch was already O(n) i just switched to a while loop to continue doing what I wanted until all condition were met then break out of the loop. Thank you for reaching out still!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was already using a switch statement and it is O(n), I decided to use a while loop and set up the conditioning around the same principles I was looking for in the switch statement, and then break out of the loop. Everything worked well. Here is what I did below.

Profile.js

```
          while (newUpdate) {
            if (
              newUpdate.username.trim().length >= 3 &&
              newUpdate.username !== User.find({ username: { $ne: null } })
            ) {
              foundUser.username = newUpdate["username"];
            }
            if (newUpdate.company.trim().length >= 3) {
              foundUser.company = newUpdate["company"];
            }
            if (newUpdate.location.trim().length >= 3) {
              foundUser.location = newUpdate["location"];
            }
            if (newUpdate.position.trim().length >= 3) {
              foundUser.position = newUpdate["position"];
            }
            foundUser.save((err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
            break;
          }
```

I fixed the main issue as well. By doing this, I was able to get usage of ".trim().length and set the condition accordingly. I did not know at first that input tags always return an empty string during validation and that their inherited property is equivalent to 0. Therefore, I was able to set a condition to render false and pass to the next function, which is why I wanted to use the switch in the first place.

Comment: Do you really need a while loop in here? It will just `break` after the first iteration.

Comment: I wanted to check all the condition before saving. I can see why there should not be a while loop since I can just set them up as single if statements. That would be a place where I could refactor and just leave them a single If statements right? or could that be refactored more past that as well? @dina

Comment: If you're trying to ensure `newUpdate` exists before you start processing, you can do a verification like `if (newUpdate)` or anything that would verify the shape you're expecting etc.